# getting Null pointer exception while injecting GoogleSignInClient while authenticating

Tags: java, android, firebase, dependency-injection, firebase-authentication

I am trying create an application with firebase authentication, while injecting the `GoogleSignInClient` it is resulting in the error

**AuthActivity.java**

```
@Inject
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient;

 private void signIn() {
      try{
          Intent signInIntent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();  //Null pointer exception
          startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
      }catch (Exception exception){
          Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
```

**AuthModule**

```
@Module
public class AuthModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    static GoogleSignInOptions provideGoogleSignInOptions(Application application){
        return new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(application.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    static GoogleSignInClient provideGoogleSignInClient(Application application, GoogleSignInOptions options){
         return GoogleSignIn.getClient(application,options);
    }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Component(modules = {AuthModule.class,
        AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

The below line of code results in error:

`Intent signInIntent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();`

Please suggest if I am missing something here

Comment: You are trying to inject a bean that has not been configured previously.   How did you configure this GoogleSignInClient?

Comment: That sounds like a dependency injection issue. If you understand Kotlin, I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/auth) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the official documentation, they have done it this way:

In your case, I dont think you have configured/created GoogleSignInClient and yet you are injecting it.

> Configure Google Sign-in and the GoogleSignInClient object
>
> In your sign-in activity's onCreate method, configure Google Sign-In
> to request the user data required by your app. For example, to
> configure Google Sign-In to request users' ID and basic profile
> information, create a GoogleSignInOptions object with the
> DEFAULT_SIGN_IN parameter. To request users' email addresses as well,
> create the GoogleSignInOptions object with the requestEmail option.
>
> // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and
> basic // profile. ID and basic profile are included in
> DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
>
> ```
> GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
>         .requestEmail()
>         .build();
> ```
>
> If you need to request additional scopes to access Google APIs,
> specify them with requestScopes. For the best user experience, on
> sign-in, only request the scopes that are required for your app to
> minimally function. Request any additional scopes only when you need
> them, so that your users see the consent screen in the context of an
> action they performed. See Requesting Additional Scopes.
>
> Then, also in your sign-in activity's onCreate method, create a
> GoogleSignInClient object with the options you specified.
>
> ```
> // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
> mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
> ```